# Why Does My Task Run When The Trigger Is Disabled? (Task Scheduler)

Tags: triggers, windows-10, taskscheduler

I have a Task in Task Scheduler with multiple triggers defined.

- Trigger 1: Runs on the weekend every 4 hours during the day.
- Trigger 2: Runs the task every 15 min every day; this one is for testing.

When I left last night, I disabled the test trigger but when I came in to work, the task had run multiple times despite the trigger being disabled and it not being a weekend (meaning the other trigger shouldn't have gone off). Any ideas what might cause this? My OS is Windows 10 Pro.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not within the bounds of discussion as described in the help center.

Comment: Looks like Super User would be a better place to ask?

Comment: Most likely. If you've got an issue with the code running in the trigger, this is the place for help with that.